# How to run a node action from bash in a github action?

Tags: node.js, bash, github, github-actions

I'd like to run a bash script in my Github Action and upload generated outputs - which are 211 validation results (2.3mb worth of text) - to a Google Sheets spreadsheet.

I have a Github Action to upload results to a spreadsheet ([Mudlet/gsheets-append-action](https://github.com/Mudlet/gsheets-append-action)), and this seems to be the simplest way to upload as gsheets does not really allow bash/curl based uploads. This is because you have to do an OAuth login and doing that by hand isn't trivial.

I have already tried storing all of the 211 validation results as individual environment variables in order to 'loop' over them using a separate job & matrix, but this seems to hit limits on how many environment variables are allowed:

```
An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/bash' with working directory '/home/runner/work/packages/packages'. Argument list too long)
```

Using a single environment variable is not workable either as the size limit on that is 48kb.

What's the best way to get bash and the node action to cooperate?

Comment: Looks like you're already contributing to https://github.com/Mudlet/gsheets-append-action. Why don't you add another input similar to [`DATA_ENV_NAME`](https://github.com/Mudlet/gsheets-append-action/blob/9e575660cb6b4ebcb2685db5293ddf580070a4f8/action.yml#L13-L15) e.g. `DATA_FILE_NAME` that would accept the CSV file path? Using a file would lift those size limits.

Comment: Issue created: https://github.com/Mudlet/gsheets-append-action/issues/22

Comment: Yep, I had the same thoughts on a CSV input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case, someone stumbles upon this first, https://github.com/Mudlet/gsheets-append-action now supports a `DATA_FILE_PATH` input parameter accepting a CSV file path to avoid [limits on the configuration variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#limits-for-configuration-variables).

Either `DATA_ENV_NAME` or `DATA_FILE_PATH` may be used according to the use case.